# Receive NSPersistentStoreRemoteChange notification when app is closed

Tags: swift, core-data, cloudkit

I use `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` to fetch/sync data across multiple devices with the same iCloud account.

```
/// ...
container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: containerName)
let description = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first
description?.setOption(
                true as NSNumber,
                forKey: NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey)
description?.setOption(
                true as NSNumber,
                forKey: NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey)

let viewContext = container.viewContext
viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy.mergeByPropertyObjectTrump

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            forName: .NSPersistentStoreRemoteChange, object: container.persistentStoreCoordinator,
            queue: .main
        ) { _ in
            Task { @MainActor [weak self] in
                // fetch new data and update widgets with it
                // ... viewContext.fetch ...
                // WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
                }
            }
        }
/// ...
```

Everything works fine when my app in the foreground. How can I achieve the same when my app is closed/ in the background? I know that CloudKit can send silent push notification which can wake up my app but I've never seen the implementation of it using CoreData `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer`